# How to select array index after Where clause using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

Suppose I have the array `string[] weekDays = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };` , and I want to find out the index of array elements containing 's'. How can I do this using Linq ?

I've tried `int[] indexOfDaysContainingS = weekDays.Where(day => day.Contains("s")).Select((day, index) => index).ToArray();`, but this returns `0,1,2` as presumably it's getting the index of the filtered `IEnumberable<string>` after the Where() clause instead. If I put the Select() first, then all I have is the index and can't filter by the days.

What do I need to change to make it work and return `1,2,3` instead ?

Comment: I know that's not part of the question, but why don't use do this with a for loop instead of Linq. You would have saved many minutes of development.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
weekDays.Select((day, index) => new { Day = day, Index = index })
        .Where(x => x.Day.Contains("s"))
        .Select(x => x.Index)
        .ToArray();
```

Not sure if this is optimal..

Comment: @Patko but how did it know to take the index from the array and associate it with the "index" which you put in the Index property?

Comment: @YonatanNir, `Select` has two overloads, one also has an index of the element as a parameter, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx. That index parameter is then saved to an anonymous object so that it can be again used in the second `Select`. I hope this answers your question?

Answer (score 15):

Patko's answer is the way to go in the general case.

Here are 2 more options:

```
// Idea only works with collections that can be accessed quickly by index.
int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, weekDays.Length)
                          .Where(index => weekDays[index].Contains("s"))
                          .ToArray();
```

With [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
// Similar to Patko's idea, except using a 'named' type.
int[] indices = weekDays.AsSmartEnumerable()
                        .Where(item => item.Value.Contains("s"))
                        .Select(item => item.Index)
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. Is there any reason why performance would be different using your first alternative vs Patko's answer for a large array ? I'm not sure which is the optimal choice.

Comment: @miket2e: Patko's answer is the general one - the `Range` approach doesn't work well with non-list sequences;  so it's hard to make a "fair" comparison. For arrays, I would *think* the `Range` approach would be faster - there's *probably* less heap allocation, it's *possibly* more cache-friendly etc. (notice the weasel words). Don't believe me though, measure! *Maybe* you shouldn't even be using LINQ here.

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
weekDays.Where(a => a.Contains("s")).Select((a, i) => i).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't believe the logic is correct in this example as the index value returned shall be after the collection has already been filtered rather than the index relative to the original collection.